# Cleaning up unreleased temporary file WARN in wso2carbon.log in wso2 esb 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In my wso2 esb server, I am seeing the below WARN very frequently and it's piling up in wso2 carbon.log

Cleaning up unreleased temporary file /opt/wso2/wso2esb-4.9.0/tmp/tmp_9205879766948865918.dat {org.apache.axiom.util.blob.OverflowBlob}

So far this error is not impacting the application but is there any way ti get rid of it.

Issue is in wso2 esb 4.9.0

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with xml data streams, the data is first stored into a fixed size buffer. Once this buffer overflows, it is transferred to a temporary file and that is what you have seen as a .dat file inside the tmp directory. Usually this temporary file should be deleted automatically after releasing the resource. But if it is not released even after the work has been done, it will be deleted by the ESB with a warning. That is what you have observed and it is not affecting to your application. So you don't want to worry about that log.

Comment: HI Charitah, Thanks for your response. Is there a way to increase size of the buffer OR is it fixed. Though it's not impacting the application but want trying to get rid of it to make logs cleaner.

Comment: Hi, It is not possible to configure externally as it is fixed by the library.

Comment: HI Charitha, Recently we started seeing out of memory and high cpu utilizations in all our production esb servers. We started seeing these errors when our xml data got increased a bit. Earlier we use to handle 40KB message but now it increased to 100KB.